# how to mimic "tail -f ... | grep ..." using less?

Tags: tail, less

When using `tail -f some/filename`, it waits for more to be appended to the file. Just like `less +F ...`.

However if I have a pipeline such as `tail -f some/filename | ...` then the `less +F ... | ...` *does not* work the same way, i.e. waiting for things to be appended to the file. It terminates. Even though the `less` man page says

> ```
>    F      Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is reached.  Normally this command would be used when already
>           at the end of the file.  It is a way to monitor the tail of a file which is growing while it is being viewed.  (The behav-
>           ior is similar to the "tail -f" command.)
> ```

How do I use `less` in this scenario - I don't want it to terminate when reaching file end. I really don't mind missing out on my pipeline for the last 10 lines if that's the tradeoff.

Thanks

Comment: Use `tail -f` instead? Could you give an explanation of why you want to use `less` here? If it has to do with some filtering of the data, then this may possibly be done some other way.

Comment: A pipe after tail and less +F? I agree with @kusalananda, provide us with more info about the actual use-case.

Comment: @desasteralex the pipeline can vary - it's Unix after all, isn't it? That said, I am using a pipeline comprising egrep and sed. At present I manage with `tail`, but `less` got so much more to offer :-)